# Connect ASP NET CORE 2.0 With Oracle

Tags: oracle, asp.net-core

When I try connect ASP NET CORE 2.0 to Oracle using the `System.Data.Oracle` Nugget, I receive an error. I understand that the issue is about `OCI.dll`.

Comment: What is the error message? What code are you using?

Comment: Unhandled Exception at startup - Cannot find OCI DLL: oci.dll

Answer (score 0):

I did find one solution for that, this error happens because Oracle is not installed in Windows OS. The nugget work when Oracle client (11 or 12) is installed on local, the 'OCI.dll' is copy to local and fix the issue. But in Apple not work, (I do not know how to install Oracle in apple)